# How to work on my project - flutter or kotlin- in two systems

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code

The problem i faced from android-studio is

```
Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/media/islamux' when creating directory '/media/islamux/Variety/FlutterProjects/dawah/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm working on flutter project in linux mint lmde6
I'm using android studio, vscode..
the project in separated folder in ssd.

flutter and dart version

```
Flutter 3.13.9 • channel stable
Framework • revision d211f42860 (4 weeks ago) • 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
Engine • revision 0545f8705d
Tools • Dart 3.1.5 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Now i installed fedora 39 but i faced a problem to run the same project in the same place
because of the mount point of fedora is not the same in linux mint lmde6

In Linux mint mount point of project is /media/username/

In Linux fedora mount point of the same project is /run/media/username

Comment: Tried adding a symlink?

Comment: More details please , how to do that ?

Comment: solve the problem as follows.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

Make sure that Android Studio and Flutter are installed on the system drive, not on a separate drive.

Create a new Flutter project.

Replace the lib, assets... etc with your folders.

Replace the

> pubspec.yml

file with the project's pubspec.yml file.

```
 flutter clean.

 flutter pub get.

 flutter pub upgrade.
```

You may need to upgrade the Flutter version, but be careful if your project contains packages that may not be compatible with the new release.

```
 flutter upgrade
```